# How to hide parameters in URL without javascript?

Tags: html, forms, query-string

My form is like this:

```
<form method="GET" action="target">
   <input type="text" name="filter"/>
   <select name="skill">
      <option>opt1</option>
      <option>opt2</option>
      <option>opt3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="number" name="level"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I would like the empty parameters **not to be shown** in the URL when the form is submitted, and this happens with the *skill* field , but not with *level* and *filter*, which are added to the Query string even though they're empty.
 How does it happen? Is it possible to prevent this from happening without using javascript?

None of these fields is required to submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible without javascript.

You can use something like jQuery to [accomplish](https://www.billerickson.net/code/hide-empty-fields-get-form/) this.

note: Using form method `POST` is the preferred way of submitting forms, and the parameters are submitted as http request body and not in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a form POST instead of GET, the form params will not appears in the query string. But that would require back end changes.

Comment: The question is specifically about hiding the parameters in the URL